# How to create new array with key and value from array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new array from an array with id property from an array of objects using javascript.

below is the data,

```
const input = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'name1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'name2',
    },
]
```

from the above input data, I want to create a new array like below

```
const output = [
    {id: '1'},
    {id: '2'},
]
```

i have tried const output= input.map((s) => s.id)

this will give output like below,

```
const output = ['1', '2']
```

but I also want the key id. how can I do it? could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: the result that you want isn't valid JS

Comment: please add a valid result. you can not have same named keys in an object.

Comment: have you tried `Object.entries(output)`

Comment: the object has other properties too apart from id

Comment: i have edited the question to result the output.

Comment: Use this `input.map(({id}) => ({id}))`

Comment: `const res = input.map(el=>({id:el.id})) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first in the object, **we must  use ","** *don't use ";"*
here is a simple example for your question

```
let input = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'name1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'name2',
    },
];

input = input.map(({ id }) => ({ id }));
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'name1',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'name2',
    },
];

/* one way is to remove name property then you will left with only id */

const result1 = input.map((item) => {
  delete item.name;
  return item;
});

console.log('result1 : ', result1);

/* other way is to create new object with id property and assign item.id */

const result2 = input.map((item) => {
  return {id: item.id};
});

console.log('result2 : ', result2);
```